# Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class com.serviceyou.com.tests.ServiceYouTest

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-14

I'm trying to run a unit test with scalatest on IntelliJ. But I'm getting this error

```
Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class com.serviceyou.com.tests.ServiceYouTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.serviceyou.com.tests.ServiceYouTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$6(Runner.scala:1213)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$6$adapted(Runner.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$filterImpl$1(TraversableLike.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1211)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

I looked at Edit Configuration, it looks good. 
Also, the test run successfully on the command line but not IntelliJ.

Also, I tried to see what other people had on stack overflow but none of the suggestion fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a gradle project and resolved by reloading the gradle project from the IntelliJ gradle window.